# running python in low resolution in macOS Monterey

Tags: macos

how can I run python.app in low resolution in macOS Monterey?

there used to be a checkbox in the app's info, but it is missing from Monterey, is there any way I could fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Apple is no longer supporting "Low Resolution Mode". But There's a trick to open application in Low Resolution Mode. You need to Edit  **info.plist** of python.app and change the key **NSHighResolutionCapable** to **false**.

Comment: I'm new to apple's ecosystem, can you guide me through that? :')